# JS - Custom Text Icon - ES6 Callback Click

Tags: javascript

```
function textIcon(_holder, _icon, _text, _on_click) {
    _holder.append(`
     <text-icon onclick="${() => { _on_click() }}">
         <icon class="${_icon}"></icon>
         <text>${_text}</text>
     </text-icon>
  `);
}
```

There is no error in **onclick="${() => { _on_click() }}"** but callback not working.

Comment: im pretty sure ${} tags need to be inside `` not ""

Comment: @user3666653, the whole html is within backticks so their use of `${}` is fine.

Comment: there is `` chars after ".append(" and before ");"

Comment: Are you using jQuery or some other library? Is that where you are getting `append()` from?

Comment: @PatrickEvans yes i have jQuery. Is there a problem with that ?

Comment: I can test it without jQuery

Comment: No just wanted to make sure that was the library you were using, you should tag it in your question so people know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

inline js is eval'ed so this:

```
onclick="${() => { _on_click() }}"
```

does not work because it just equates to

```
()=>{ _on_click() }
```

Which is just a function. What you want is a function call so:

```
onclick="(${() => { _on_click() }})()"
```

Which will end up being

```
(()=>{ _on_click() })()
```

And being eval'ed as an immediately executed function. And of course all of that could have just been:

```
onclick="_on_click()"
```

Though even when using the immediately executed function, this will still not work in calling `_on_click` as the function still needs to be in global scope in order to be executed.

You can instead just insert the html and add the event listener on the element:

```
var textIcon = $(`<text-icon>
                      <icon class="${_icon}"></icon>
                      <text>${_text}</text>
                  </text-icon>`);
//Add it to the dom
_holder.append(textIcon);

//Add click event listener
textIcon.on('click',_on_click);
//And if for some reason you need an arrow function
textIcon.on('click',()=>{
   _on_click();
});
```

Demo

```js
function textIcon(_holder, _icon, _text, _on_click) {
  var textIcon = $(`<text-icon>
                        <icon class="${_icon}"></icon>
                        <text>${_text}</text>
                    </text-icon>`);
  _holder.append(textIcon);
  textIcon.on('click', () => {
    _on_click();
  });
}

textIcon($('#container'),'someicon','some text',()=>console.log('in callback'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: ok i think your first idea **onclick="(${() => { _on_click() }})()"** is true and great, but now chrome tells me **Uncaught ReferenceError: _on_click is not defined** i think i have an error in passing call back too. thanks by the way :)

Comment: @n-shz, Yes, read the rest of the answer, you cannot use _on_click_ as it is not a globally defined function. Functions called within inline js have to be global